# converting a dictionary<string, string> to read from a file

Tags: c#

I require help here in reading value from a file rather than hardcoded stuff in code:
I have this dictionary

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> projectCustomerNameMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"Lara","Lara" },
            {"Tiger","Lara" },            
            {"Panther","Lara" },            
            {"Dice","Dara" },
            {"bird","Dara" }

        };
```

and I reading it in this line in a method in same class like this:

```
customerName = projectCustomerNameMapping
                            .FirstOrDefault( q => q.Key.IndexOf( (string)jsonContent["Project"] ) != -1 ||
                            ((string)jsonContent["Project"]).IndexOf( q.Key ) != -1 ).Value ?? "Para";
```

I would like to know how can I replace my above hard coded dictionary in some file in the solution and read it from file. In dictionary my first value is project and 2nd value is customer name

Comment: `Dictionary<String,String> dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< Dictionary<String,String> >( File.ReadAllText( "file.json" ) )`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `.json` file to read when your app loads or when you will read your data.

So, your `.json` will have the following structure

```json
{
    "Lara": "Lara",
    "Tiger": "Lara",
    "Panther": "Lara",
    "Dice": "Dara",
    "bird": "Dara"
}
```

And you can use the [Newtonsoft](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) Lib to parse your json file like @Dai showed at comments

```
Dictionary<string,string> projectCustomerNameMapping = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< Dictionary<string,string> >( File.ReadAllText( "file.json" ) )
```